# Examples of special isometries

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Are there examples of (distinct) Hilbert spaces $H_1$=$(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1)$, $H_2 $=$(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2)$ and a linear operator $V: H_1\to H_2$ such that $V^n: H_1\to H_2$ is an isometry $\mathbf{??}$ for every $n=1,2,...$.

Note that:

1) $H_1$ and $H_2$ have the same underlying linear space structure, and we look for $V$: $||V^n(x)||_2=||x||_1$ for all $x\in H_1$ with $||x||_k=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle_k}$, $k=1,2$)

2) if $V: K\to K$ is an isometry on a Hilbert space $K$, so is $V^n$ (i.e. $||V^n(x)||=||x||$, for all $x\in K$), so the question is if we can find such isometries between $\underline{\rm distint}$ Hilbert space structures.

Comment: How do you define $V^n$ if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are entirely distinct?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy: the vector spaces are the same, only the scalar products are asked to be different. Paulo should probably have written $V:H \to H$ to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you ask $V$ to be invertible (you do not seem to do, but the usual definition of an isometry includes it).

(**Edit:** paragraph corrected thanks to Nick Weaver's comment)
If $V$ is not asked to be invertible, then the answer is **yes**: take $H=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ be the usual $\ell^2$ product, $V$ be the right shift and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_2$ be equal to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ except that it is rescaled on the first coordinate (e.g. $\langle u,v\rangle_2=2u_1v_1+\sum_{i>1} u_iv_i$).

If $V$ is asked to be invertible, then the answer is **no**: simply look at the action of $V$ on scalar product 
$$V\cdot\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle = \langle V^{-1}\cdot,V^{-1}\cdot\rangle.$$
Then you ask for two distinct points (in the space of scalar products) such that one is fixed and the other is mapped to the first one. This is clearly impossible for an invertible map.

Comment: The left shift is a co-isometry, not an isometry. Interchange $H_1$ and $H_2$ and use the right shift.

Comment: (Also your comment when $V$ is invertible is a little weird ... why not just say that if $V$ is a bijection and preserves the inner product then $H_1$ and $H_2$ cannot be distinct?)

Comment: Final comment --- in the context of Hilbert space operators, the usual definition of an isometry does not include invertibility. Isometry is $V^*V = I$, co-isometry is $VV^* = I$, unitary is $V^*V = VV^* = I$.

Comment: @NikWeaver: thanks for the correction (now edited) and the terminology, which I didn't know. For the weirdness of the invertible part, I do not quite get what you write: there are a priori two inner products. One can certainly state this part in many ways.

Comment: No problem.  I withdraw the "weirdness" criticism, there is nothing wrong with your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the $l^2$ example. I think the above inner products give rise to equivalent norms on $l^2$, so we may wonder if such is the case in general?

Comment: @Paulo: I am not sure of what is considered best behavior, but that seems to deserve a new question.